# OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError · data not multiple of block length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, cryptography, blowfish

I am consuming base64-encoded blowfish encrypted double value 3rd party API data.

And with a given Key, I am decrypting it on my end.

my decryption method looks like this:

```rb
   def blowfish_decode(base64_encoded_encrypted_value, md5key)
    unpacked_key  = [md5key].pack('H*')
    encrypted_value = Base64.decode64(base64_encoded_encrypted_value)

    # create cypher with no padding
    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('bf-ecb').decrypt
    cipher.key = unpacked_key
    cipher.padding = 0

    str = cipher.update(encrypted_value) << cipher.final
    value = str.unpack("G").first
    return value
  end
```

I am getting the following error from time to time:

```
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError · data not multiple of block length
```

Anyone knows why this would be happening only occasionally?

Comment: It could be that the input is using URL safe base64 rather than normal Base 64. Try using [`urlsafe_decode64`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-urlsafe_decode64).

Comment: It would help to have an actual example data that causes the error.